# Can the Infinity Stones be destroyed?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, infinity-stones

The way the lore goes; the 6 Infinity Stones were created when the universe itself was created and represent all aspects of life. The Space Stone, Reality Stone, Power Stone, Mind Stone, Time Stone and Soul Stone when collected together represent the ultimate power in the universe.

Thor believed/told Thanos that the Space Stone (Tesseract) was destroyed on Asgard. Obviously it wasn't because Loki had lifted it when he put Surter's crown into the Eternal Flame but could it have been if he didn't snatch it? Can they be destroyed by any means available to any creature or circumstance in the cosmos?

Comment: Redundant but, I addressed this in my answer here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186142/do-the-infinity-stones-have-unlimited-power/186166#186166

Comment: Have you... seen *Endgame* yet?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Or *Infinity War*.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The question makes it clear that it is about destruction by conventional methods.

Comment: @Parrotmaster: the last line of the question is “Can they be destroyed by any means available to any creature or circumstance in the cosmos?” That seems pretty wide-ranging.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yes, and the movie does not answer that question. "by any means" is not answered by "the gauntlet/Scarlet Witch could, so yes". He wants to know if physical force or some device made by Stark could destroy it.

Comment: @Parrotmaster: oh I see what you mean.

Answer (score 26):

That would very much depend on how you define “destroy”. Thanos in *Avengers: Endgame* reduces the Infinity Stones to atoms by using their power against themselves.

> **Natasha Romanoff:** Where are the Stones?
>
> **Thanos:** Gone. Reduced to atoms.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

However, right after that, he states he destroyed them this way.

> **Bruce Banner:** You used them two days ago!
>
> **Thanos:** I used the stones to destroy the stones. It nearly killed me. But the work is done. It always will be. I am... inevitable.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

Now if you go by the definition of rendering them unusable, which the Avengers and Thanos believe he did, then yes you can very much destroy them. However, they were still there just broke up into atoms which one could say meant they weren’t destroyed.

It’s also worth noting what The Ancient One tells us about the Infinity Stones. She says they create the flow of time and removing one would make time split. As this did not appear to happen after Thanos destroyed the Stones, we can probably say they weren’t “removed” as such so weren’t 100% destroyed.

> **The Ancient One:** The Infinity Stones create what you experience as the flow of time. Remove one stone and that flow splits.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

So Thanos with all the Infinity Stones at his disposal destroyed the Stones but couldn’t completely destroy them. But then, of course, it’s worth noting if he wanted to completely destroy them or if he just wanted to render them unusable. Or of course, even if they could be completely destroyed. Essentially it all depends on what you mean be destroy in this context.

And of course Thanos' actions aside it's also worth mentioning that Wanda destroyed the Mind Stone in Vision's head in *Avengers: Infinity War*. Again though the Stone appears to be destroyed but no lost completely. It looks to be reduced to fragments/atoms but not gone, gone. So your interpretation of what destroyed means plays a big part in whether this counts or not.

---

Whilst this question is about the MCU, it is also worth noting that in the comics the Infinity Gems have been destroyed on a few occasions. For example, as we see in *New Avengers Vol. 3* Issue 3 when Cap is using the Infinity Gems to push away the other Earth.

[image: Comic page where the Infinity Gems are destroyed]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: Or time did split, I'm not sure it would be apparent to the people living in either "stream" of the split

Comment: @GordonBennett It's more likely it didn't split but yeah I left that sentence open for the possibility that it did.

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning that Wanda Maximoff successfully destroyed the Mind Stone.

Comment: @DanDoubleL Excellent point, I was too focused on Endgame. Added a section on that.

Comment: Of course, in a universe where time travel is a thing, "nothing's ever really gone" as it were.  Hence the entire plot of Endgame after that point.

Comment: Lmfao, since when is "broken up into atoms" not the same as destroyed lmao

Comment: @theonlygusti Because of what they are. It's not a car or another mundane object, they literally create the flow of time and have immense power. The Stone form might be destroyed but they are still in existence as atoms and so not technically destroyed themselves.

Comment: "Remove **one** stone and that flow splits." - Maybe if you remove them all, you don't have the lack of balance that leads to the split?

Comment: @RossThompson Remember the preceding comment: _"The Infinity Stones create what you experience as the flow of time."_ It might not cause a split but it could cause something even more disastrous.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Perhaps so. We really don't have a lot of hard evidence about what would happen with the some or all of the stones.

Answer (score 17):

If Thanos was unable to destroy them when he had the power of *all* of them available, then there isn't likely any greater power available in the universe to destroy them.

Note that according to the directors Thanos did *not* manage to destroy the stones:

> ...according to the Russos, the Infinity Stones aren't actually lost: *"Thanos only reduced the stones to the atomic level. The stones are still present in the universe."*
>
> <sub>[(source)](https://screenrant.com/avengers-endgame-director-russos-infinity-stones-still-exist/)</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure Thanos *wanted* to destroy the stones. His goal was to render them unusable, not to unmake the universe or create a new timeline

Comment: I’m not sure why you’ve used a directors quote as evidence either when this is stated in the film.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Not having a transcript available to quote is the main one, but also, as noted in your answer, the movie isn't completely clear.

Comment: A comment from a director of a movie is as easily overturned as he is replaced.

Comment: The quote definitely adds information that is *not* stated in the film. I had taken "reduced to atoms" in the movie to mean "there is no fragment of them remaining larger than atomic scale", and thought that was very clearly satisfying the ordinary meaning of "destroy". If you destroy my car but try to argue that all of its atoms still exist I certainly wouldn't be very impressed! That applies to everything that has been "destroyed" throughout human history, outside of a nuclear reactor or particle physics laboratory!