# Could the Infinity Stones be used to achieve anything?

Tags: marvel, infinity-stones

Thanos’ whole aim was to get the Infinity Stones in order to remove half the living beings in the universe at the snap of a finger, but, is this all the Gauntlet and Stones are able to do. For instance, if someone got the Stones could they give themselves instant wealth, make grass turn red, make someone love them?

For that matter could Iron Man instead of disappearing Thanos, make his army hate him and refuse to follow him, or could he have made Thanos lose his will to rebuild the universe.

Are the Stones basically a wishing machine or are they limited in what they can achieve?

To confirm I am looking for examples or answers from any canon source, both MCU and in the comics.

Comment: Whilst the dupe is specifically about love, the quote in the answer and the detail it gives clearly applies to the general case.

Comment: [Also related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186142/58193).